# Where to store user metadata with graph api?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure AD B2C Graph API to create and manager users. Users have data and progression so I wanted to know, how should I go about storing information about the user in my app (such as how much gold the user has)?

I want to grab their userPrincipalName or their objectId and use that as a primary key in a separate database to keep track of app related information but before doing that I wanted to know if this was the correct way to do it with graph API, unless there's a standard graph API has for storing app data per user?

Ideally I don't want to be able to associate data with specific users for security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2):

With Azure AD B2C you can extend your schema with custom attributes and read/write to them using Azure AD Graph API.

Please see how to [create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#create-a-custom-attribute) and this page for how to [use custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes) with the Graph API.

In my opinion, if you just need to store data, use Azure AD B2C with custom attributes, but if you also need some complex logic when reading/writing the properties, or even crate some relations between properties, then consider a custom data store.

Comment: When you say to use a custom data store do you mean like a separate mysql database or something?